# Help with a linearly dependent proof on differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Show that any two solutions $y_1$ and $y_2$ of the equation $y' + p(x)y = 0$
are linearly dependent.

How do I prove this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Note that if $y_1$ is a solution then $y_1' = -p(x)y_1$.  Now use the Wronskian.

Comment: would the wronskian involve y1 y2 and its derivatives?

Comment: Yes.  $$W(y_1,y_2) =\begin{vmatrix} y_1 & y_2 \\ y_1' & y_2'\end{vmatrix}$$

Comment: okay so that works out to be y1y'2 - y2y'1

Comment: Use my hint.$ $

Comment: okay so plug -p(x)y1 in for y'1?

Comment: That's right.$ $

Comment: i dont quite understand where to go from there?

Comment: trying to review for my exam

Comment: You've gotten $y_1(-p(x)y_2)-y_2(-p(x)y_1)$, right?  Can that be simplified?

Comment: -p(x)[y1y2-y2-y1] ====> -p(x)[0] = 0 ???

Comment: and then because that is 0 it would be dependent?

Comment: Right.  $W(y_1,y_2)=0$ everywhere thus $\{y_1,y_2\}$ is a linearly dependent set.

Comment: okay so its enough for me to write the 2x2 matrix find the determenent, plug in -p(x) then simplify and show it is equal to zero so therefore dependent?

Comment: Yes.  That's what Wronskians are good for -- determining linear (in)dependence.  When they equal zero everywhere, the set is linearly dependent.  When there's even one point in the domain where the Wronskian is non-zero, then the set is linearly independent.  In this case $W(y_1,y_2)$ is zero everywhere so we immediately make our conclusion.

Comment: okay so if i was to do a example to show linear independence they would likely give me a domain to prove it under? or if they didnt when i got to my answer i would give the domain conditions it is under?

Comment: If they don't provide a domain then the mean the largest domain over which everything is defined.  Usually it'll just be all real numbers, but for instance if they gave you $$y' +\frac yx = 0$$ then the domain is $(-\infty, 0)\cup(0,\infty)$ because you can't divide by $0$.

Comment: okay thanks, i understand what is happening now. thanks for your time you have been a help

Answer (score 0):

Generally, as the equation is a linear first order one, it has only one basic solution, and so each two solutions of it are dependent.

But to make a proof, assuming $y_1$ and $y_2$ as the two solutions of your equation, we have

$y_1'=-p(x)y_1$ and $y_2'=-p(x)y_2$.

Then, the wronskian of these solutions is

$w(y_1,y_2)=y_1y_2'-y_2y_1'=-y_1y_2p(x)+y_1y_2p(x)=0$,

and so they are dependent.